# L is a typo here?

Tags: word-usage

In the article here

http://archive.vector.org.uk/art10500970

MTA (Mail Transfer Agent): L handles the mail traffic between two servers, so this is what actually “sends” the email – and receives it at the far end.

What does L mean?

```
L handles the mail traffic between two servers
```

It is a typo?

Comment: There is no way for us to know, because it could be the name of a server or have some kind of specific technical meaning in the context of the source.  Is there more information you can provide that helps explain why you think it's a typo?

Comment: http://archive.vector.org.uk/art10500970

Comment: Definitely a typo